# Where to modify threadcount in Weblogic 10.0 MP2

Tags: weblogic, threadpool

I need to modify the number of threads available in my Weblogic 10.0 MP2 environment for some perf benchmarking but I cannot seem to be able to find where exactly that option lies.

Can anyone share this info please? thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with config.xml in ur domain? self-tuning-thread-pool-size-min or something along those lines?

Answer (score 4):

Weblogic 10 does not use execute thread queues like in previous versions (i.e. Weblogic 8.1 and older)

This concept is now replaced with [Work Managers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_wls/self_tuned.html).

**These are self-tuned, i.e. WLS will auto-tune the number of threads every 2 seconds** based on how it sees the need to increase threads for the application load.

You can confirm this from the console, it will show the increasing number of execute threads as the load increases.

You can use the work manager and constraints to make sure your applications get certain criteria met.

Such as certain web apps or EJBs can get a higher share of threads and so on.

For a quick read see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/workload-management-088692.html

and

http://m-button.blogspot.com/2009/02/tuning-default-workmanager-on-weblogic.html

Secondly, are you running in dev mode or production mode.

If dev mode, you can try this cmd line parameter

`-Dweblogic.threadpool.MinPoolSize=100`

but I am not sure if it will work, so it's better to leave it to Work Managers